# Want to execute a python code from a groovy script

Tags: python, groovy, katalon-studio

I have a situation where I need to call/execute a python script from a groovy script. How can I do that?

Below is the code which I have written in groovy to execute a python script

```
def task = ["/Users/amiteshshukla/Documents/Work/PythonTest/Test.py"]
def executeTask = task.execute()
executeTask.waitForOrKill(1000)
println (executeTask.text)
```

And this is the sample python code which I am trying to execute through groovy

```
class Test:

    def callMyName(self):
        print("****My name is amitesh****")


t = Test()
t.callMyName()
```

When I execute the groovy script I expect this output:
  "****My name is amitesh****"

But instead, I am getting this in ouput.

```
task = ["/Users/amiteshshukla/Documents/Work/PythonTest/Test.py"]
executeTask = task.execute()
executeTask.waitForOrKill(1000)
println(text)
```

Comment: Add a shebang line to your python script `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Check this out: https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-use-python-in-katalon-studio/16023.

Comment: Thanks, @rdas. It worked. You are a savior. I was trying to run this code for 2 days. If you can give the same comment as an answer. Then I can mark that as a right answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a shebang line to your python script. That way the OS know that it needs to invoke your script through the python interpreter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Test:

    def callMyName(self):
        print("****My name is amitesh****")


t = Test()
t.callMyName()
```